# How to get mouse position with bokeh server?

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh, interactive

I want to get the mouse position in a plot via a callback function using bokeh server. A solution for the latest bokeh version 2.0.2 would be great.

So far I found this [old solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39744122/bokeh-server-get-mouse-position) which does not work any more due to deprecation of the tool_events attribute in the figure object.

I have found this [javascript example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-user-interaction-events) which does not work for the boekh server context.

Has someone an idea how to achieve this with bokeh?

Comment: Related - I needed to do this in `holoviews` with a `bokeh` backend, here's how I did it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71107256/1177832

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get mouse position after every move, regardless of whether the cursor is over any glyph, you can just listen to the `mousemove` event:

```py
from bokeh.events import PointEvent
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure()
p.circle(0, 0)


def on_mouse_move(event: PointEvent):
    print(event.x, event.y, event.sx, event.sy)


p.on_event('mousemove', on_mouse_move)

curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Also `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` may be of interest to you.

Comment: How can someone save or access the coordinates? I see the coordinates in Anaconda Prompt but I do not know how I can get them in Spyder.

Comment: "How can I access" - well, you have the coordinates right there in the callback function. And I have no idea about Anaconda Prompt and Spider, I've never used them.

Comment: Is there also the possibility to access the index of the datapoint one is hovering over?

Comment: At the time of writing the answer, there was no built-in way - you had to find the index manually. I have no idea whether something has changed in more recent Bokeh versions.